# Finding Inequality of 4 variables using Nested If else only

Tags: python

Lets say I have 4 variables, a,b,c and d.

I'm trying to write a code(in the shortest formate) using only If Else (in nested formate) to arrange the variables in accensending order.

I'm sure their possibly are ways to do it smothly but using this method do you think if the code can be shortened

Do you guys have any simpler way of finding inequality in such a way

**```

````
a=19
b=10
c=1
d=8

if a>b:
    print()
    if a>c:
        print()                                                         #ALL OK
        if a>d:
            print()
            if b>c:
                print()
                if c>d:
                    print("a>b>c>d")
                else:
                    print("a>b>d>c")
            else:
                print()
                if b>d:
                    print("a>c>b>d")
                else:
                    print("a>c>d>b")
            
        else:
            print()
            if b>c:
                print("d>a>b>c")
            else:
                print("d>a>c>b")
    else:
        print()
        if a>d:
            print()
            if d>b:
                print("c>a>d>b")
            else:
                print("c>a>b>d")
        else:
            print()
            if c>d:
                print("c>d>a>b")
            else:
                print("d>c>a>b")
else:
    print()
    if b>c:
        print()
        if b>d:
            print()
            if a>c:
                print()
                if c>d:
                    print("b>a>c>d")
                else:
                    print("b>a>d>c")
                    
            else:
                print()
                if a>d:
                    print("b>c>a>d")
                else:
                    print("b>c>d>a")
        else:
            print()
            if c>a:
                print("d>b>c>a")
            else:
                print("d>b>a>c")
    else:
        print
        if c>d:
            print()
            if a>d:
                print("c>b>a>d")
            else:
                print("c>b>d>a")
        else:
            print("d>c>b>a")
```
`
```**
````

Comment: `print(sorted([a, b, c, d]))`

Comment: I have just started Learning Python and was currently on Nested If else topic, so thought why not

Comment: If you want to use this particular approach, I think this can't be shortened considerably.

Answer (score 1):

Probably don't want to use nested statements in this scope, as you can see it get's unweildly very quickly.

```
a = 19
b = 10
c = 1
d = 8
# Note you can shorten the nesting by using multi-conditional (might not be the term!)
if a > b > c > d: print("a>b>c>d")
elif b > c > d > a: print("b>c>d>a")  # and so on..
# but you're still looking at hardcoding every possible permutation of [a, b, c,d] or in the event of a dataset with X elements..
# Nested if's are useful but not in this scope

# In the context of this problem it would be better to sort
# the data and create a string based on that
as_dict = {"a": a, "b": b, "c": c, "d": d}
sorted_d = sorted(as_dict, key=lambda x: as_dict[x])[::-1]
print(">".join(sorted_d))
```

Comment: I believe OP does not want another solution not using nested if, as this problem is quite challenging and good for beginners

Comment: @PythonProgrammer I provided context about multi-conditional statements, and one of the many potential other ways to instead solve the issue. And I think it's fair to not only know how to use nested statements, but when not to.

Answer (score 1):

#Pure pythonic You can try uisng `and` which will be clean & Append results to str order accordingly

```
a=19
b=10
c=1
d=8
s=''
how_many_var =4

for i in range(how_many_var):
    
    if a > b and a > c and a > d:
        print(a)
        a=0
        s += 'a>'
        
    elif b > a and b > c and b > d:
        print(b)
        b=0
        
        s += 'b>'
    elif c > a and c > b and c > d:
        print(c)
        c=0
       
        s += 'c>'
    elif d > a and d > b and d > c:
        print(d)
        d=0
        
        s += 'd'
print(s)
```

output #

```
19
10
8
1
a>b>d>c
```

Comment: This is a great way to do it, really makes you experiment with your conditions

Comment: Why are you setting each var to 0 though?

Comment: Once max value is found it will enter to loop...we need to eliminate that value for next comparisons by setting value to zero...if it is not zero every time we get same value as max